# draw a graph where the distance between vertices correspond to the edge weights

Tags: algorithm, graph, drawing, euclidean-distance

Is there an algorithm that gives me coordinates of vertices in a graph, when I give him a weighted graph and the **edge weights** between vertices points to the **distance between vertices**?

Something like:

```
public _ArrayOfCoordinatesForVertices_ **super_hyper_algorithm**(weighted_graph){  
     return _foo_;  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is in general not possible: Imagine a graph with 3 nodes n1, n2, and n3.

now consider the following distances:

```
n1-n2: 4
n1-n3: 1
n2-n3: 1
```

(This violates the triangle inquality).

Answer (score 5):

What you are referring to is called [Multidimensional scaling (MDS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) and you should find plenty of implementations now you know how to search for it.

Like others said, to some extent, it is impossible to draw a perfect graph without violating some of your constraints (the distances between points). MDS algorithms are specifically targeted at minimizing such violations.

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is drawn in the [Euclidean Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) you can't do that, because, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497329/draw-a-graph-where-the-distance-between-vertices-correspond-to-the-edge-weights/5497617#5497617) you could violate the [Triangle Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Usually, you can visually represent edges' weights by using different colour (i.e. by mapping weights to a colour-map), or by using different thickness of the edges (i.e. by mapping weights to a thickness scale).

Answer (score 0):

OK i have found a [library](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/) for python and it creates a graph image for me :) and i can give weights for edges like attribute: Weight of edge. In dot, the heavier the weight, the shorter, straighter and more vertical the edge is.